# Extracting n number of rows from a table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I want to fetch the first n record and count of a particular field from a **table Sale**.

My sale table is :

[image]

I use the query for extracting material and his count :

```
Select top 5 material ,count(*) from sale group by material;
```

It gives me output in the form of :

[image]

but I want output in the form of :

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: You have 5 records for coal. If you only want to have 4, maybe you should delete one of those?

Comment: Either that, or explain yourself better.

Comment: I don't care what records after first 5 records .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are getting at is that you just want the to operate over the first 5 rows?

```
select material, count(*)
from
(
  Select top 5 material from sale 
) a
group by material
```

I don't have access, so I can't check the precise syntax, but it should be more or less that!

Answer (score 2):

First retrieve the 5 rows you want.

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 material FROM sale ORDER BY saleinvno;
```

Then do your counting based on those 5 rows.

```sql
SELECT sub.material, Count(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 5 material FROM sale ORDER BY saleinvno
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.material;
```

**Note**: `SELECT TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not reliable.  I guessed `saleinvno` for ordering.  Use a different field for the ordering if I guessed wrong.